# How to direct Facebook users to the page with the Like button upon clicking an app invitation?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I have been searching for a few hours and cant seem to find answer to my problem, so i came here for help.

I have a like-gate on facebook. After user is trough he gets a friend invite window, this one works fine too, shows friends, text and invites people normally. The problem is when a user is invited to app, his link directs him directly to app without frame(no like button to continue).

I could fix this by using another like button, but i dont want to do that. Is there any way for me to create this sort of walkaround?

1. People who didnt like the page get the splash screen. [Not liked page](http://shrani.si/f/2t/bw/30q3PgEG/1.jpg)
2. People who liked, get inside.
3. People who were invited, get the direct link without like button... [link to the pic](http://shrani.si/f/1Y/P3/3qiIjq2/3.jpg)

I am pretty new at developing so please try to explain as simple as possible. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The problem is when a user is invited to app, his link directs him directly to app without frame(no like button to continue)."

This will redirect your visitors from the page without the Like button to the page with the Like button.

```
<script>
    if(document.URL.indexOf("fb_source") != -1)
    {
    top.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_NAME/PAGE_ID/APP_ID";
    //change accordingly
    }
</script>
```

"People who didnt like the page get the splash screen. People who liked, get inside."

Do a FQL query to check whether your visitors have already liked your page.

```
$page_id = PAGE_ID; //change accordingly
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => APP_ID, //change accordingly
    'secret' => APP_SECRET, //change accordingly
    'cookie' => true,
));
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

function userIsFan()
{
    global $page_id, $facebook, $access_token;
    $fql = "SELECT uid from page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id='".$page_id."'";
    $param = array('method' => 'fql.query',
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'query' => $fql,
    'callback' => '');
    $response = $facebook->api($param);
    if (isset($response[0]))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If they have liked your page, direct them to your application(yourApplication.php), else direct them to your splash page(splashPage.php) asking them to like your page.

```
if (userIsFan())
{
    header("Location: yourApplication.php"); //change accordingly
}
else
{
    header("Location: splashPage.php"); //change accordingly
}
```